# Wifi speed is only 5Mb/s for different adapters

Tags: wifi

I set up wifi-router from eth0 -> wlan0 on my rasp pi 2 raspberian. 
But it has the same ~5Mb/s speed for different usb wifi adapters (RT5372, RTL8192CU, and some Chinese nano-wifi too).
eth0 speed is ok and about 30Mb/s
I have /dev/random, extra power for wifi-hub, 10class SD card, but I still have 5Mb/s.

What can I research to increase wifi router speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ieee80211n and ieee80211d fixed my issue

```
country_code=US
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
hw_mode=g
```

I got 30 Mb/s that is good enough!

Comment: Could you please mention where to add these parameters? Module config, boot parameters?

Comment: that is hostapd config